# flashdevelop not compiling correctly

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

When I try to compile my application in flash develop. it wont compile. even if I put a simple trace in the Main class. Nothing happen. the sdk is in the correct place.

Comment: nothing but a blank screen. no response. I had it working before. now its not. not sure what i could of done

Comment: some projects work , some dont

Comment: is there something suppose to be in the lib file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a few different things. But make sure for these tests that you have a trace in your main constructor.

First, go to your project settings (Project > Properties). On the Output tab **un**-check "no output", and select "Play in popup" in the "Test Movie" drop down menu. Then test your application (F5).

Take not of a few things; What appears in the output panel (if you don't have it open, go to View > Output Panel). Does it show something like this?

```
/*
Running process: C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe ...
Using the Flex Compiler Shell.
Building ProjectName
mxmlc -load-config+=obj\ProjectNameConfig.xml -debug=true ...
Starting new compile.
Loading configuration file C:\Flash\flex_sdk_3\frameworks\flex-config.xml
Loading configuration file C:\Flash\Projects\ProjectName\obj\ProjectNameConfig.xml
obj\ProjectName634012614944137992 (228743 bytes)
(fcsh)Build succeeded
Done (0)
[Capturing traces with FDB]
*/
```

Are you missing any of the above lines in your output panel while testing you application?

If you don't see any of this in your output, or your own trace, then create a new test project, add a trace, and try again.

Comment: thanks alot for the response. I did what you said and what happens is it opens up flash cs4 and displays the text "No documents open" in its out put panel. could the two be conflicting ?? I had flashdevelop working before and I have been working in flash cs4 alot lately. I decided to go back to flashdevelop for my next project and thats when I run into the issue

Comment: nevermind I have it resolved. But your actions lead to my discovery. My output window was removed and therefore was not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

do you have it linked to the compiler correctly?
There is a chance that upgrading the compiler or FD could have changed the setting.

Also you could try compiling through the Flash IDE. As a test or a solution.